# How to show pixel position and color from a QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qpixmap

I'm developing a custom widget with QGraphicsScene/View and I have no prior experience with it.

The custom widget is an image viewer that needs to track mouse movement and send signal(s) to it's parent dialog / window.  The signal(s) will be the position of the pixel under the mouse cursor and it's color (in RGB).  A status bar will use that information.

I use a QGraphicsPixmapItem to display the image I load from a file in the scene.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to implement the [`mouseMoveEvent`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mouseMoveEvent) in your custom item. In this function you can easily get the mouse position calling the [`pos`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#pos) function. You can get the rgb value if you transform the item's pixmap into image and call the [`pixel`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#pixel-2) function. You should consider storing the `QImage` as member variable in order to avoid multiple transformations. Finally you have to emit a custom signal. Sample code follows:

```
void MyPixmapItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * event)
{
    QPointF mousePosition = event->pos(); 
    QRgb rgbValue = pixmap().toImage().pixel(mousePosition.x(), mousePosition.y());
    
    emit currentPositionRgbChanged(mousePosition, rgbValue);
}
```

**Notice** that `QGraphicsItems` do not inherit from `QObject` so by default **signals/slots are not supported**. You should **inherit from `QObject`** as well. This is what [`QGraphicsObject`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsobject.html) does. Last but not least I would advise you to enable [mouse tracking](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) on your `QGraphicsView`

Answer (score 1):

I found the mouseMoveEvent approach to not work at all, at least not with Qt5.5. However, enabling hover events with setAcceptHoverEvents(true) on the item and reimplementing hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent * event) worked like a charm. 
The Qt docs on mouseMoveEvent() provide the clue:

"If you do receive this event, you can be certain that this item also received a mouse press event"

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qgraphicsitem.html#mouseMoveEvent