# Hover events not working in QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: qt4, hover, qgraphicsitem

My class structure is:

A class called **FloatingButtonItem** , inherits **QGraphicsPixmapItem**.

```
class FloatingButtonItem : public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
```

(...)  And reimplements these five functions.

```
protected:

void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
```

Each of them just change the value of a BOOLEAN variable and print a message.

And in the **constructor** i have:

```
FloatingButtonItem::FloatingButtonItem(MyGraphicsScene* scene,  QGraphicsItem* parent) :  QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent)
```

The FloatingButton gets painted perfectly but the **hover events are not received**.

And before you ask it: YES, i added this line on the creation:

```
  **setAcceptHoverEvents(true);**
  setFlag(ItemIsMovable, true);
  setFlag(ItemSendsGeometryChanges, true);
  setZValue(20.0);
```

And the item appears in front of the rest of the items perfectly.

After creating it, i add it to the scene by using "addItem" function.

Is it any problem with the creation? With the parenting?

On the other hand I have **another class** that inherits from **QGraphicsPolygonItem**,
and what i called GenericItem, a class that is created like this:

```
class GenericItem : public QObject {

Q_OBJECT

...
```

And it DOES work with hover events. Apparently it is the same... 
Adding Q_OBject and making it inherit from QObject doesn't work.

**EDIT:** I add another comment:
I checked the bounding rectangle. It is ok. The size is not 0.

**EDIT 2:**  Concerning the bounding box:

I reimplemented boundingRect function too:

```
QRectF boundingRect () const { return boundingRect_; }
```

And bounding rect is calculated in the creation taking the Pixmap selected like this:

```
boundingRect_ = QRectF( -pix.width()/2, -pix.height()/2, pix.width() , pix.height());
setPos(-pix_.width()/2,-pix_.height()/2);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that this is the constructor for your class: -

```
FloatingButtonItem::FloatingButtonItem(MyGraphicsScene* scene,  QGraphicsItem* parent) 
      :  QGraphicsPixmapItem(parent,scene)
```

If you look at the constructors for QGraphicsPixmapItem, the documentation shows these: -

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem * parent = 0)
QGraphicsPixmapItem(const QPixmap & pixmap, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0)
```

Neither constructor take a QGraphicsScene as the 2nd parameter, which is what you're passing to the base class.

You should be creating your pixmap item and calling: -

```
pScene->addItem(floatingButtonItem);
```

Comment: Thanks!  But i changed it passing only the "parent", which should work, but sadly it doesn't.   I set the pixmap afterwards and calculate the bounding box from it later on. I did that already, adding the item after creating it.

Comment: "caclulate the bounding box...later on" - Are you not overriding the boundingRect function? If not, then that's likely to be the problem. The boundingRect function is used to calculate when the mouse is over the item. The function should return the bounding Rect in local coordinates.

Comment: Thanks!   
I added info on my question on the bottom about what i did for the boundingRect. I had already reimplemented it.

Comment: Your setPos is strange to pass the coords of the centre of the image. That sets the position of the item relative to its parent, or if there isn't one, relative to the scene. Have you tried debugging your code and checking if boundingRect is called when you move over the item? Also, can you move the item around? Another debugging tip is to draw the boundingRect in the paint function to see it's what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: Thanks. My paint function works using the bounding rect: painter->drawPixmap(boundingRect_.toRect(), pixmap_);
And it is drawn perfectly. It enters the boundingRect for this item in particular (i checked it was it). What else is left??

Comment: You could try inherit directly from QGraphicsItem and store a QPixmap in the class. Then render it in the draw function. See if that makes a difference. If it doesn't, it may be that a higher level object is blocking events.

Comment: I found something that can help you with the answer...
I changed QGraphicsPixmapItem to QGraphicsRectItem, copying the other items i had. NOW IT WORKS!. The hever effect. i created the rect using by hand a QRect(-15,-15,30,30), like the original pixmap. It paints a blue box that has a hover event.  How come this happens with my pixmapItem?? Any ideas?

Comment: This answer may help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090005/qgraphicspixmapitem-mousemoveevent-when-not-grabbing

Comment: And this: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15214-Mouse-events-in-QGraphicsPixmapItem-and-QGraphicsTextItem

Comment: I learned more about this problem. I found out constructing this way:  FloatingButtonItem::FloatingButtonItem(DesignerGraphicsScene* scene,  QGraphicsItem* parent) : QGraphicsRectItem(QRect(-5,-5,10,10), parent) ,  works.  But saying just QGraphicsRectItem(parent) without the rect and calculating it afterwards, or even creating the parent object inside the constructor doesn't work. ONLY setting the size there.

Comment: From the other links, it may be that calling it that way also sets the shape() function to return correctly, which you may need to do manually if you set the rect afterwards.

Comment: YES!!! super yes. It works implementing the shape function too. Finally i tried implementing the Shape function: 

QPainterPath FloatingButtonItem::shape() const
{
  QPainterPath path;
  path.addRect(boundingRect());
  return path;
}

Please, Merlin069, write your answer as an answer and i´ll vote it.

Comment: Oh. I´m sorry, you already did. I mark it!. Thanks a lot Merlin!